# Making redirects after an axios post request with express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redirect, axios

I'm having trouble getting redirects to work after accepting a post request from Axios. I do know that the request is being sent and that it at least gets some response from the '/' route, because my console logs "index", "user verified" which is what should happen when someone makes a get request to '/'. The problem is that the page doesn't load. I've even seen in the networking tab on google chrome that index.js is loaded but the page will not change no matter what I've tried! Is there any reason for this?

Other redirects that I've made do seem to work. For example, the index page will reroute to /login if the user is not logged in. This seems to only be an issue with the post request and I have tested it with and without passport authentication (obviously changed that you would need to be logged in to redirect) and it's the same result. So I do not think passport is causing the issue.

You can refer to package.json below to see what I am using

axios code:

```
axios.post('/login', {username: username, password: password})
        /*.then(response => res.redirect('/'))*/
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

express side: I have console logs to alert myself during testing

```
 server.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    console.log("Index");
  if (req.user){
       console.log("user verified");
        res.redirect('/');
        app.render(req,res, '/',req.query);
  } else {
      console.log("user not logged in");
      res.redirect('/login');
  }
})

server.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        console.log("Logging in");
        res.redirect('/');
  } else {
        console.log("Passwrod Incorrect");
        return res.redirect('/login');
  }
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "layout-component",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node ./server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^0.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^2.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.5",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
    "next": "^5.1.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.79.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are making an ajax call to server using axios.  In ajax redirect response from server may not be taken into consideration by default, like normal browser requests. Better send a 401 response json to client and redirect from client.

Comment: I do not think I'm using Ajax at all. I am just using the acios

Comment: Not sure if I'm using Ajax at all. Unless axios uses it. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: I've been working on this problem for over 5 hours in the last day and I just cannot get it working the way home it should. I'm not sure whether the post request is not being sent right or if I am receiving it in correctly. I can console.log and see the data is being sent (,can print the username and password ) and also see that it tries to redirect index and it even loads the logging from the index page it redirects to. The browser doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh. My axios config is entirely default. I didn't setup anything . Just yarn add axious and wrote the post  function. Should I have written a config?

Answer (score 26):

I figured this out after. Apparently, you cannot do a redirect from the server when you make an Axios post request. At least not the way that I was doing it (with the default Axios config.) You need to do the page change on the client side. Here's how I did it.

This really stumped me because I was receiving data from my redirect route using the other method but the page wasn't loading.

Also, for some reason using Next.js, the passport.js "successRedirect" and "failureRedirect" JSON doesn't seem to work. That's why I've written the routing the way I have and did not include those in the passport.authenticate() function. I hope this helps somebody!

My Axios submit function:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {username, password} = this.state;
    axios.post('/login', {username: username, password: password})
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.redirect == '/') {
                window.location = "/index"
            } else if (response.data.redirect == '/login'){
                window.location = "/login"
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            window.location = "/login"
        })
}
```

The post request in my Express server

```
server.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) {
        var redir = { redirect: "/" };
        return res.json(redir);
  } else {
        var redir = { redirect: '/login'};
        return res.json(redir);
  }
})
```

Comment: This is working but the problem is that, page is refreshing everytime

Comment: Same. The page is refreshing everytime. WHAT'S THE SOLUTION?

Comment: Clever solution! just use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Although it won't be a server-side redirect, this can be accomplished cleanly on the client-side with Axios' "interceptor" which can intercept requests or responses before they get passed to `then`/`catch`:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: how do you redirect the user here? If you redirect prior to returning `Promise.reject(error)` you get an `onunhandledrejection` error.

Comment: For my case, I simply wanted to do a manual redirect to an error page so I did the following:

axiosAPI.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response;
}, error => {
  console.error('Axios error:', error);
  if (error.response.status === 401) {
    window.location = '/error';
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});