# Express won't redirect after passport authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy, passport.js

I'm running a server on port 5000 using express, and I used create-react-app to run a server on port 3000. To manage authentication, passport.js.

I use http-proxy-middleware to proxy some endpoints to the express server. Here's my code:

*setupProxy.js*

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        proxy("/signup", {
            target: "http://localhost:5000",
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    );
}
```

*passport.js*

```
passport.use(
"local-signup",
new LocalStrategy(
    {
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    async (req, username, password, done) => {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
            username: username
        });
        if (existingUser) {
            console.log("User already exists");
            done(null, false);
        } else {
            const user = new User();
            user.username = username;
            user.password = password;
            user.save();
            console.log(user);
            done(null, user);
        }
    }
)
```

);

*App.js*

```
app.post(
    "/signup",
    passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/",
        failureFlash: true
    })
);
```

*Component.js*

```
// some code here

onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
        .post(
            "/signup",
            {
                username: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password
            },
        )
```

If I make a request to `http://localhost:3000/signup` using postman it just works (I get printed "user already exists", or and a new database entry is created and I get printed the user info). But if I use the form in `Component.js` with the onSubmit function mentioned above, I get nothing. I'm not redirected, the user is not created.

The network tab of the console indicates a `http://localhost:3000/signup` with code `302 found` (which makes sense) and then I get a `http://localhost:3000` with code `304 not modified`.

I'm freaking out, since I just can't find any answers on stack overflow. I've been on this for days, completely stuck... Can anyone give me a hint on what is going on?

**EDIT:** Thanks to the kind help of you guys I refactored the code. It seems I'm getting somewhere but now I get 400 Bad Request. Here's my updated code:

*App.js*

```
app.post(
    "/signup",
    passport.authenticate("local-signup"),
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.user) {
            var redir = { redirect: "/" };
            return res.json(redir);
        } else if (!req.user) {
            var redir = { redirect: "/profile" };
            return res.json(redir);
        }
    }
);
```

*Component.js*

```
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
        .post("/signup", {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.redirect == "/") {
                console.log("Success");
                window.location = "/";
            } else if (response.data.redirect == "/profile") {
                console.log("Failed");
                window.location = "/profile";
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error");
            window.location = "/profile";
        });
}
```

I get printed out "Error", and if I print the error I just get 400 Bad Request...

Comment: I don't believe an axios POST call will cause your browser to redirect. Have you tried submitting this login with a form? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601795/making-redirects-after-an-axios-post-request-with-express

Comment: XHR won't follow the redirect. You need to handle it manually on the client (browser).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I refactored the code according to your kind suggestions, but now I get 400 Bad Request... I'll update my question, could you please take a look? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I solved my problem! Thank you very much, guys! You're the best... Finally I'm out of this stuck place.

I followed [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) great tutorial and I just used the html form instead of the axios post method. It just worked :)

Here's my new (working) code:

*App.js*

```
app.post(
    "/signup",
    passport.authenticate("local-signup", {
        successRedirect: "/", // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect: "/profile", // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
    })
);
```

*Component.js*

```
const Profile = () => {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>Signup</h1>
        <form action="/signup" method="post">
            <div>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="username"
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    name="password"
                />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">
                Signup
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

};