# ExpressJS: res.redirect() does not work. How to redirect in single page app?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

## Issue:

I have a static single page application in which I press on a Submit input that sends a POST request using Axios from a Vue component to an Express server in which I handle the POST and try to redirect to another page, but `res.redirect("/home")` and/or `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"));` do not redirect.

## Expected behaviour:

I would like to redirect to `/home` after submit.
Everything else works just fine.

## Server File:

```
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const path = require("path");

// serve the Vue Interface
const buildLocation = path.join(__dirname, "../dist");
app.use(express.static(buildLocation));
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(express.static(buildLocation));

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"));
});


app.post("/dhcpIP", function (req, res) {
  // check if request body is empty
  if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)
    return;
  // doing things that work
  res.redirect('/'); // this doesn't work
});

const http_server = http.createServer(app);

http_server.listen(http_port);
```

I build the Vue CLI application so that I can obtain the `dist` folder. In the `dist` folder I have an `index.html` that contains the whole application.

## Vue component that sends the POST request:

```
<template>
  <form action="javascript:void(0);" @submit="sendData" novalidate="true">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

const serverURL = location.origin;
const server = axios.create({ baseURL: serverURL });

export default {
  name: "DHCP",
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
      ssid: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendData: function() {
      if (this.ssid === "" || this.password === "") return;
      let currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
      console.log("currentUrl:");
      console.log(currentUrl);
      server
        .post(currentUrl, { ssid: this.ssid, password: this.password })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

## Router File

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    redirect: "/home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/dhcpIP",
    name: "DHCP",
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dhcpIP" */ "../views/DHCP.vue")
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  // base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

I have tried writing as little code as possible.

Comment: I think the problem is that your Vue component is not handling the redirection. You can try if it works in principle with a browser or a program for testing APIs.

Comment: I will look into that. Any other information will help.

Comment: its a SPA so there is actually just 1 route its the `/home`, the other routes are handled by javascript. you could instead of redirect send him the index.html file `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../dist/index.html"));`

Comment: @Ifaruki It doesn't work. It sends the html file back to the client as an object, but the page doesn't change. Not even the inputs refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In your post route you are already returning something

```
app.post("/dhcpIP", function (req, res) {
  // check if request body is empty
  if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)
    return;
  // doing things that work
  res.redirect('/'); // this doesn't work
});
```

**The return statement ends the function execution.** That being said: You are returning "*some things that work*" and after that you use the `res.redirect` method, which is ignored because **the function has already returned a value**.

Comment: Not really, no. The `if` statement checks if what ever I'm receiving is empty and if it's empty then it returns and ends the function execution. The entire code that I have after that `if - return` statement works just fine as long as I send something along the POST request. `res.redirect()` or `res.sendFile()` both send a response back to the Axios request, so the function doesn't end at the `if - return`.

Answer (score 0):

use `router.push()` instead, since you're not redirecting, but using the router

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

if what you want to achieve is to move away from the SPA by the redirect, then you can change the window.location depending on the server response, in that case, send a 301 or 302 from the server, and add an axios interceptor for it.

https://simplecheatsheet.com/axios-interceptors/

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and explain why is your solution better than mine ? And also include some example code ? Thank you.

Comment: Also, I don't think that I want to move away from SPA. Why would I want that ? Your answer is very ambiguous to me. Care to explain more ?

Comment: I don't know how to use `router.push()`. I have tried `this.$router.push(currentUrl);` but it returns an error: `Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/dhcpIP".`. Can you complete your answer with more details ?

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out the problem using [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601795/making-redirects-after-an-axios-post-request-with-express).
Apparently, if you are doing an AXIOS post, you can't redirect from the Express server and you must handle the redirect in the AXIOS method.
**I haven't found any explanation or documentation on this subject yet. When I do I will update this answer.**

I did it like this:

## Server file:

```
app.post("/dhcpIP", function (req, res) {
  // check if request body is empty
  if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)
    return;
  // doing things that work

  if(errors.length != 0) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  } else
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

## Vue component:

```
    sendData: function() {
      if (this.ssid === "" || this.password === "") return;
      let currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
      server
        .post(currentUrl, { ssid: this.ssid, password: this.password })
        .then(res => {
          if(res.status == 200) {
            alert("Settings have been saved.");
            window.location = currentUrl;
          } else {
            alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
```