# Next.js: redirect loads the site, but doesn't redirect the user

Tags: typescript, redirect, next.js

I have a Next.js serverless logout function:

```
import magic from './magic';
import { withSessionRoute } from './sessions';

export default withSessionRoute(async function logoutHandler(
  request,
  response,
) {
  try {
    if (request.method === 'GET') {
      if (request.session.user) {
        await magic.users.logoutByIssuer(request.session.user.issuer);
      }

      request.session.destroy();

      return response.redirect(302, '/').end();
    }

    const message = 'This endpoint only supports the GET method.';
    return response.status(405).json({ message });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

The important part is `response.redirect(302, '/').end();`.

I trigger this in a button's `onClick` handler:

```
const logoutRoute = '/api/logout';

const logoutRequest = () => axios.get(logoutRoute);

async function handleLogoutClick() {
  return await logoutRequest();
}

// ... later

<button onClick={handleLogoutClick}>
  {t('user-authentication:logout')}
</button>
```

However, when the request resolves, Next.js loads `/`, but it doesn't redirect in the browser.

```
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /Users/janhesters/dev/my-proj/.env.local
event - compiled client and server successfully in 943 ms (217 modules)
wait  - compiling /home (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 173 ms (594 modules)
wait  - compiling /api/logout...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 96 ms (612 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 56 ms (620 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully in 76 ms (58 modules)
```

[image]

What is missing so that the frontend actually redirects to `/`?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Making redirects after an axios post request with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601795/making-redirects-after-an-axios-post-request-with-express)? Axios won't automatically follow the redirect you send from the API route, you have to handle it on the client-side (inside `handleLogoutClick`).

Comment: @juliomalves I don't think this is related. I have another project where I trigger that `logoutRequest` inside of a Redux saga, and it works there. Also swapping `axios` with `fetch` for that request neither fixes the issue. So I don't think it's an axios problem ...

Comment: It's not that it's an axios problem, it's just how it works. You have to handle the redirect in your client-side code. Using fetch will have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my specific case `Router.push` was successfully happening.

Something in `getServerSideProps` was causing the instant redirect back to login.

```
export const getServerSideProps = withIronSessionSsr(
  async function getServerSideProps({ req, locale }) {
    const user = req.session.user;

    if (!user) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/login',
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }

    return {
      props: {
        user: mapUserSessionToUserProfile(user),
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
          'common',
          'home',
          'user-authentication',
        ])),
      },
    };
  },
  sessionOptions,
);
```

My issue is that `request.session.user` is `undefined`, but that's a separate issue.