# How to Redirect in Nextjs with Expressjs as a server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, next.js

I'm using a http://localhost:3000/ in frontend while http://localhost:5000/ in backend. I call a request in http://localhost:5000/api/home. Nextjs is not redirecting what should I do?

```
// Expressjs
app.post('/login', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const checkUser = await client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$1', [username]);
  const checkPassword = await client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE password=$1', [password]);
  
  if (checkUser.rows[0].username === username && checkPassword.rows[0].password === password) {
   console.log('Success Login');
   return res.redirect('/home');   
 }
 return next(Error.internal('Login Not Successful'));
});
```

```
// Nextjs
const Login: FC = () => {
    const apiRequest = async () => {
    const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/register', { withCredentials: true });
    return redirect('/home')
   // I don't know how to respond to the redirect from Api...
  };
  const { isLoading, isError, loading } = useQuery('homeKey', apiRequest);
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (isError) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Error...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }


};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Making redirects after an axios post request with express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601795/making-redirects-after-an-axios-post-request-with-express)? Have your Express endpoint response with `res.json({ redirect: '/home' });`, then handle it on the client-side `if (res.data.redirect) { router.push(res.data.redirect); }`.

Comment: Thank you so much! All along I thought when I redirect from Expressjs, it will redirect the Nextjs page too. The word server-side rendering confused me.